# XQuery performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, performance

Why does this quite simple xquery takes 10min to execute in sql server (the 2mb xml document stored in one column) compared to 14 seconds when using oxygen/file based querying?

```
SELECT model.query('declare default element namespace "http://www.sbml.org/sbml/level2";
for $all_species in //species, $all_reactions in //reaction
where data($all_species/@compartment)="plasma_membrane" and $all_reactions/listOfReactants/speciesReference/@species=$all_species/@id
return <result>{data($all_species/@id)}</result>') from sbml;
```

Comment: Could you post one xml (model) field?

Comment: only 1 row, but the data in that model column is 2mb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"//" kills MSSql, use a so exact path as possible instead: http://scarydba.wordpress.com/2009/11/30/xquery-for-idiots/

Comment: +1 The 3-character change from that link sped up my query by 10x.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a schema declaration for your XML? Did you place appropiate indexes on it?

- [XML Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187508(SQL.90).aspx)
- [Indexes on XML Data Type Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx)
- [`CREATE XML INDEX` (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097.aspx)
- [Adding Namespaces Using WITH XMLNAMESPACES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx)
- [`CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION` (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176009.aspx)